# Validate bootstrap wizard on "Next" button click

Tags: javascript, c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently using bootstrap wizard with progress bar of this [template](https://themesbrand.com/minia/layouts/form-wizard.html) to create a form by steps as:

```
    @model MyProject.ViewModels.Test.TestViewModel
    <form asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Create" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="needs-validation" role="form" novalidate>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="twitter-bs-wizard-nav nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#progress-station-profile" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="step-icon" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Station Profile">
                    <i class="bx bxs-user-detail"></i>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="progress-station-profile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="CallLetters" class="form-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="CallLetters" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Call Letters is required.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Market" class="form-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Market" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Market is required.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Format" class="form-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="Format" class="form-select" required>
                        <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option>
                        <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option>
                        <option value="Test 3">Test 3</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Format is required.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Frequency" class="form-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Frequency" class="form-control" autofocus/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="pager wizard twitter-bs-wizard-pager-link">
            <li class="next">
                <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Next
                    <i
                        class="bx bx-chevron-right ms-1">
                    </i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
     ..///next step etc..
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-1" value="Save"/>
    </form>
```

As you can see, some of my fields are required, and I want to achieve to validate those fields via client-side validation when the user clicks the "Next" button because it validates at the end of the form (submit button), and the user has no idea what step was wrong. So it will be awesome if I can validate it when the user clicks the next button

**UPDATE**

I already find a way to show validations as:

```
//first step
<div class="tab-pane step" id="progress-station-profile">
//fields here

   <button onclick="return validate('progress-station-owner')" 
   class="btn btn-primary">
    Next
   </button>
</div>

//Step 2

 <div class="tab-pane step" id="progress-station-owner">
  //fields here

  <button onclick="return validate('progress-station-owner')"  
   class="btn btn-primary">
    Next
   </button>
 </div>

//Step 3

 //fields
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-1"> Save Station</button>
```

And I use function as:

```
function validate(step){
    let window = document.getElementById(step);

    window.querySelectorAll("input,select,textarea").forEach(e=>{
      if(!e.checkValidity()){

        e.classList.toggle("is-invalid");
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
      }
    });
    return true;
  }
```

So, if I try to click button Next validations don't allow me to continue, that is correct, but now I have a big problem:

1. If I click Next on the first step it goes to the second step and shows the second step but it tries to execute the "Next" button of the second step automatically, so validations appear once step 2 showed up. Why is it happening?

Comment: Hi @Jesus, Did you use this [bootstrap wizard](https://github.com/gwrey/bootstrap-wizard), if you use any other js library, pls share with us for it may have any other influence.

Comment: I use [twitter bootstrap wizard](http://github.com/VinceG/twitter-bootstrap-wizard) @Rena

Comment: I also added the wizard with progress bar [template](https://themesbrand.com/minia/layouts/form-wizard.html) I currently using